# Zookeeper api exists method version

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I just want to know how does the `zookeeper` api's  exists (String path, boolean watch) method works because I have read the docs and I am confused by it.

It states that if watch is true a watch is left on the znode which is triggered by an operation on the node but how is that watch processed (I know how, but not in case of this specific method) because no callback is being specified in this method or this version of method?

Comment: Based on the docs, it looks like some of those calls are synchronous, so there is no need for a callback. Except for the async version.